# What does this statement about algorithms mean?

Tags: algorithm, theory, graph-theory, computation-theory

"The cost of the algorithm X is linear in the area of the largest used ellipse?"

Does this mean that the cost of algorithms X grows linearly as the area of the ellipse is increased?

Note, that the area of the ellipse is increased by doubling, which means exponentially, right?

Comment: For the first two paragraphs, it should be right - but what do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei in each iteration of the algorithm, the area of the ellipse is increased by doubling it, that is why I said it is increased exponentially

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne When we talk about the cost of complexity of algorithms it's always assumed that the cost of the algorithm can be represented as a function with some number of inputs. So for example, if we have an algorithm `f(n)` we might say `f grows linearly` meaning if `n` doubles then `f` doubles and so on. In this case you are talking about the area of the ellipse... whose value changes _during_ the algorithm. That doesn't really make sense in the canonical definition of an algorithm's "cost". If you can compute the cost with respect to the _initial area_ then that would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is the area the algorithm will be O(A).

If you consider (x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1 then your algo will be O(a*b)

If you double the ellipse area at each iteration of your algorithm you'll have a quadratic growth of the area but the total complexity will be O(An) where An is the area during last iteration

**EDIT**

I'll go a little in depth:

Your algo will do f=A0+A1+...+An operations where *Ai* is the Area at the *i-th* iteration
we can rewrite the formulation in as f=A0+2*A0+4*A0+...+2^n*A0

O(f) = O(2^n*A0) where 2^n*A0  = An

Take a look also at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Wouldn't it be `O(a^2+b^2)`, not `O(a*b)`?

Comment: Ellipse area could be written as A=PI*a*b

Comment: @NicolaPezzotti can you please elaborate a little bit more on this part of your answer "but the total complexity will be O(An) where An is the area during last iteration". why the total complexity depends on the area during the last iteration? A simplified explanation would be easier to understand for me. Pardon my ignorance and lack of knowledge in this field. :'(

Comment: @NicolaPezzotti does you explanation change if my statement is changed the following way: "The cost of the algorithm X is linear in the area of (the largest) used ellipse?"

Comment: Is exactly what I said :)

Answer (score 1):

The area of an ellipse is quadratic (N^2), not exponential (2^N).  The statement means that the cost is a linear function of N where the area is a function N^2.

Comment: One nitpick: O(N^2), when N and M is on the same order.

Comment: I beg to differ. The cost is a linear function of _N_, where the area is also a linear function of _N_.

Comment: in each iteration of the algorithm, the area of the ellipse is increased by doubling it, that is why I said it is increased exponentially @zim-zamo'pootertoot

Comment: Yes but it still linear in the area of the ellipse. The complexity will be linear in the area of the last iteration